# How to Correctly Multi-Thread a DLL Called at Run-Time in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, dll

All,

I wish to write a plugin .dll to be used/called by a .NET application called at runtime. My .dll is a WinForm and displays the (computationally expensive) operations being undertaken. The .dll is called from the main application are invoked via .NET `System.Reflection`. I have to provide to the calling application the *NameSpace*, *Class* and the *Method* I want to invoke.

I would like to multi-thread my .dll so that it is more UI friendly and I am only really familiar with `BackgroundWorker`s.

**EDIT: Extension to question.**

So, I call the .dll as follows:

```
if (classType != null)
{
    if (bDllIsWinForm)
    {
        classInst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
        Form dllWinForm = (Form)classInst;
        dllWinForm.Show();

        // Invoke required method.
        MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(strMethodName);
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            object result = null;
            // The method being called in this example is 'XmlExport'.
            result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInst, new object[] { dllParams });
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Else not a WinForm do simalar.
    }   
}
```

So then in the WinForm .dll I want to multi-thread the time consuming work so that I can display what is going on. So in the .dll, using `BackgroundWorker` I have:

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker; // Global.    

public string XmlExport(object[] connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        bgWorker.DoWork +=  new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
        bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWorker_ProgressChanged);
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        // Wait until workerThread is done.
        threadDoneEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        threadDoneEvent.WaitOne();
        return strResult; // Global String strResult
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then I have the `DoWork` event handler:

```
void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    strResult = (string)this.XmlExportBgw(ref thisWorker); // Or should I use bgWorker?
    e.Result = strResult;
}

public string XmlExportThreaded(ref BackgroundWorker thisWorker) 
{
    try
    {
        // Some expesive work...

        // UI.
        InfoBall infoBall = new InfoBall(); // Class containing processing information.
        // Set infoBall parameters here...
        (thisWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(infoBall.progressBarValue, infoBall);

        // Some more expensive work...

        // UI.
        (thisWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(infoBall.progressBarValue, infoBall);
    }
    //...
}
```

The `ProgressChanged' event is

```
void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // UI.
    InfoBall someBall = (InfoBall)e.UserState;

   // Update process information.
   if (someBall.showRichTextBox)
   {
       this.richTextBox.AppendText(someBall.richTextBoxText);
       this.richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
   }
   return;
}
```

In addition to the above code I have the usual `RunWorkerCompleted` etc.

The calling application has been written to allow the user to call thereown .NET .dlls at runtime. The .dll I am trying to put together is a time intensive one and one that will only be supplied to particular users. I have run the above code and the problem is that it will not update the user interface correctly. That is that you cannot manipulate (resize, click etc.) the `Form` and it does not print and progress information until the very end of the processing when it only prints the final message out multiple times. However, it is correctly producing the .xml files I require. What am I doing wrong? Should I be invoking the .dll method from a separate thread?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Remove the threadDoneEvent.WaitOne() call.  Starting a thread and then waiting on it completely defeats the reason for using a thread.  And prevents the RunWorkerCompleted event from running, the one you want to use to process the thread result.

Comment: I don't want to pass back to the calling application until the .dll has done its work though. This way, the thread does its work and the WinForm that displays what the .dll is doing remains open. The main issue is that the UI for my .dll is not updating properly? Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: The ProgessChanged event won't fire either.  You cannot wait.

Comment: One more thing though. How then do I stop the calling application proceeding before the .dll is finished? Do I create another thread then invoke the .dll from that, waiting on this 'master' thread? What would be best here? Thanks again...

Comment: You don't stop it from proceeding, you *continue* proceeding when you got a result.  That's why the RunWorkerCompleted event is there.  Whatever you want to do after the wait call, move it to an event handler for that event.  The more formal definition of it is a state machine.  The *async* and *await* keywords in the next version of C# make it easier.  Asynchronous programming is a bit of an art without that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of methods you are tryng to execute in that dll. I am assuming they are not asynchronous meaning your main thread (application) will stop until they are done executing. An easy example could be demonstrated with the Messagebox.show("myMessage"); method. For example how could you execute 3 message boxes at once? it will not be possible without using multiple threads. Hope this methods helps:

```
    public void SomeMethod()
    {


        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            // this code is going to be executed in a separate thread
            MessageBox.Show("hello");    

            // place additional code that you need to be executed on a separate thread in here            

        }));

        thread.Start();
    }
```

then if I call that method 3 times as:

[image]

I will now be running 4 threads on my program. The main thread plus the 3 calls that I created.

Comment: Thank you that is great, it has reminded me about using threading this way! But I cannot launch the .dll this way as I don't have access to the calling application source code - I can only pass a namespace & class & method. However, say my WinForm class in the .dll is one of your `MessageBoxes` I want to update that message box with progress information as well, which means I want to multi-thread my method that does all the work but provide information to the user via the form. I was thinking about using the *The Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern*? Thank you very much for your answer.